# How to Prevent this error with RSpec and Mongoid in rails when generating RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rspec, mongoid

I tried installing rspec and mongoid in a project (Following the example from the book 'Rails Deep Dive'), and I getting errors when I try to run the generator from RSpec.

here is the gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'devise', "~> 1.4.2"
gem 'mongoid', "~> 2.1.8"
gem 'mongoid_spacial', '~> 0.2.13'
gem 'haml', '~> 3.1.2'
gem 'bson_ext', '~> 1.3.1'
gem 'rails-backbone'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.6.1'
  gem 'mongoid-rspec', '~> 1.4.4'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 1.0.1'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 1.1.0'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 0.6.7'
  gem 'jasmine', '~> 1.0.2.1'
end
```

I generated a mongo config file using a generator, and here is the result:

```
development:
  host: localhost
  database: loccasions_development

test:
  host: localhost
  database: loccasions_test

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
  host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
```

I can confirm that MongoDB is up and running, I am able to access the web browser interface. However now, when I run `rails g rspec:install` I get the following errors:

```
NOTE: Gem.available? is deprecated, use Specification::find_by_name. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.available? called from /home/glenn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/jasmine-1.0.2.1/lib/jasmine/base.rb:64.
host is not a valid option for Mongo::MongoClient
/home/glenn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bson-1.8.2/lib/bson/bson_c.rb:24:in `serialize': wrong number of arguments(4 for 3) (ArgumentError)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not using the bson_ext gem, probably because it's to old and apparently bson-1.8.2 has an issue.

You could remove:
gem 'bson_ext', '~> 1.3.1'
and try bundle install  (This might install bson_ext by default)

or change:
gem 'bson_ext', '~> 1.3.1'
to
gem 'bson_ext'

and do a bundle upgrade bson_ext (This should force and upgrade to bson_ext)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used the HEAD for all gems as given below and added mongo_ext (I don't think it changed anything though):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'mongoid_spacial'
gem 'haml'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'mongo_ext'
gem 'rails-backbone'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'mongoid-rspec'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'jasmine'
end
```

I re-run the mongoid generator

```
rails g mongoid:config
```

in order to re-create a proper mongoid.yml and then the rspec installer

```
rails g rspec:install
```

That's all. The versions of the gems I use are:

```
bson_ext (1.8.2)
  bson (~> 1.8.2)

mongo_ext (0.19.3)
mongoid (3.0.21)
  activemodel (~> 3.1)
  moped (~> 1.2)
  origin (~> 1.0)

mongoid-rspec (1.6.0)
  mongoid (>= 3.0.1)
  rake
  rspec (>= 2.9)
mongoid_spacial (0.2.16)
  activesupport (~> 3.0)
  mongoid (>= 2.3.0)
```

And comment out

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
```

in spec_helper.rb